# rendered form isnt saving any input into database, why isnt it working?

Tags: python, django

I tryed to add validation to ContactModel, by doing Forms.py but I went too far away with it and now dont know to fix it. Can someone help ?

```
def addContact(request):

    form = ContactForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ContactForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            # form = Contact(
            # full_name = request.POST ('fullname'),
            # relationship = request.POST ('relationship'),
            # email = request.POST ('email'),
            # phone_number = request.POST ('phone-number'),
            # address = request.POST ('address'),
            # )
            form.save()
        return redirect('/contact')
    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'contact/new.html', context)


def contactProfile(request,pk):
    contact = Contact.objects.get(id=pk)
    return render(request, 'contact/contact-profile.html', {'contact': contact})
```

In my opinion in Views I have big mess.. When I fill up all fields data isn't sending to database.

forms.py:

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from .models import Contact

class ContactForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Contact
        fields = '__all__'
```

models.py:

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Contact(models.Model):
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    relationship = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=254)
    phone_number =models.CharField(max_length=20)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.full_name
```

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
“Fix this code” is not a Stack Overflow issue.  We expect you to make an honest attempt, and *then* ask a *specific* question about your algorithm or technique.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing documentation and tutorials.

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (MRE).  Show where the intermediate results differ from what you expected.
We should be able to copy and paste a contiguous block of your code, execute that file, and reproduce your problem along with tracing output for the problem points.  This lets us test our suggestions against your test data and desired output.
Since you haven't specified a problem, and haven't shown any attempt to test parts of your code, you do not yet have a Stack Overflow question.

Comment: @artur-jasiński, If my answer didn't help you, also share your `contact-profile.html`.

Comment: @NKSM can you please have look one more time into it please ?

What I find out is up to form=ContactForm(request.POST) print statement is printing but after "if form.is.valid()   inst prining anything

Comment: @ArturJasiński, please share your part of html, where you render your form. Don’t use the answer, for asking if updating your question. Thanks!

Comment: @NKSM
`<form action="" method="POST">
{% csrf_token %}
<section class="contact-info">
<div class="info-line">
<i class="fas fa-phone icon-gradient"></i>
<input  type="text" class="type"  name="fullname" placeholder="Full Name" {{ form.full_name }}
</div>

<div class="info-line">
<i class="fas fa-user-circle icon-gradient"></i>
<input type="text" class="type" name="relationship" placeholder="Relationship" {{ form.relationship }}
</div>

and so on {{form.address}} and {{form.email}}
`
Im sorry for the formating -.-'
Is here option to get someone and share my screen to fix it?

Comment: @ArturJasiński, you can simple update your question to share your additional info.

Comment: @NKSM where can I update my question ? Im getting flustrated because of 1 thing, im spending 6hours already to try new codes,watching tutorials, learning about forms etc etc. and Im ending up with nothing, and I know that for someone expercienced for exaple you it is 2min of work,

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your form is not valid and it redirects always to contact.
You should to use redirect only if the form is valid. Otherwise you will never see which errors your form contains.

Try the following code:

```
def addContact(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ContactForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('/contact')
     else:
        form = ContactForm()
    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'contact/new.html', context)
```